# A strange problem with torch.optim: the variable changes, but the difference between the old and the updated variable is shown to be zero

Tags: pytorch

I stumbled upon a rather weird issue while debugging a larger code in PyTorch. A simple instance to reproduce the issue is here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11kBaxMOxN9i0X1vtaX47Yz7rkkHz7Kpu

As you can see, the variable x gets updated in every epoch (see that their norms are different), however, the norm of their difference (rel_diff) turns out to be zero. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`rel_dif` (`change_in_x`) ranges from ~55 to ~400 and all your results are pretty typical for neural network.

BTW. Next time post your code, link to colab could be additional. Please see [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Originally, I had `x_old = x.detach().data`. Changing that to `x_old = x.detach().clone()` solved the issue.